# I want to get the randomly picked key value from the dictionaries list but I got a type error.(note the list is long so putting a index is difficult)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
def data_change(account):
  data_name = data["name"]
  data_desc = data["description"]
  data_country = data["country"]
  return f"{data_name}, is a {data_desc}, from {data_country}"

print(f"option A : {data_change(data_a)}")
```

*The above code is data I want to process for the random data to display.
the list dictionary below are the first 2 example data*

```
 data = [
    {
        'name': 'Instagram',
        'follower_count': 346,
        'description': 'Social media platform',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Cristiano Ronaldo',
        'follower_count': 215,
        'description': 'Footballer',
        'country': 'Portugal'
    }]
```

and the error display is
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

on the line: data_name = data["name"]

yes, I searched for numerous solutions but it didn't get my problem solved.

like from this link

[https://www.learndatasci.com/solutions/python-typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-or-slices-not-str/#:~:text=This%20type%20error%20occurs%20when,using%20the%20int()%20function](https://www.learndatasci.com/solutions/python-typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-or-slices-not-str/#:%7E:text=This%20type%20error%20occurs%20when,using%20the%20int()%20function).

if u want to want the full file for the code ask me ok. it is a work in progress

Comment: If `data` is a *list of dicts*, you can't access `data['name']`. If anything: `data[0]['name']`. More likely you want to *loop* over `data` and print each dict's values.

Comment: `data` is a list of entries and `data_change` seems like it should operate on entrie using the argument `account`, but you do not use account at all. You use the global `data`. Try `data_change(data[0])` to pass the first element to the function, also change the code in `data_change()` to use `account['name']` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is a list and not a dictionary so you use zero based index to enumerate the items in the list. You could enumerate the items via a for loop like this:

```
def data_change(data):
    ans = []
    for account in data:
        data_name = account["name"]
        data_desc = account["description"]
        data_country = account["country"]
        ans.append(f"{data_name}, is a {data_desc}, from {data_country}")
    return "\n".join(ans)
```

Comment: thank you! Mazimia for your answer that was a basic mistake. ivvija a similar answer (it's a comment) too.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `data` is a list with two dictionaries in it.
With `data_name = data["name"]` you try to access this list but `name` is not an integer, so you get the `TypeError`.
Your list only has two entries, so you can access it with `data[0]["name"]` or `data[1]["name"]`.

Edit: Iterating over the dicts in your list as Mazimia stated, seems like a good idea.